# Jquery Incrementing field names

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following on from my previous **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256916/jquery-adding-cloning-form-fields-increment-name)**

I've now got a form that when clicking add, adds a new input field to the form incrementing the field name and input text by one each time. eg:  phone_number1, phone_number2 etc

The jquery I'm using is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var phone_number_form_index=1;
    $("#add_phone_number").click(function(){
        phone_number_form_index++;
        $(this).parent().before($("#phone_number_form").clone().attr("id","phone_number_form" + phone_number_form_index));
        $("#phone_number_form" + phone_number_form_index).css("display","inline");
        $("#phone_number_form" + phone_number_form_index + " :input").each(function(){
            $(this).parent().find('span').text('Phone number ' + phone_number_form_index);
            $(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name") + phone_number_form_index);
            $(this).attr("id",$(this).attr("id") + phone_number_form_index);
            });
        $("#remove_phone_number" + phone_number_form_index).click(function(){
            $(this).closest("div").remove();
        });
    }); 
});
```

This JFiddle shows the form working and when adding a new row the field name is incremented as is the input text. 
http://jsfiddle.net/yezw6c51/25/

However if I remove a field, the numbering can get messed up.

eg:

- With one field the input text and field names are Phone Number 1 /
  phone_number1
- With two fields the input text and field names are Phone Number 1 &
  Phone Number 2 etc
- With three fields the input text and field names are Phone Number 1 &
  Phone Number 2 & Phone Number 3 etc

if I then remove phone number 2 using the remove button I end up with 1 & 3, clicking add starts at 4.

Is there any way if I delete 2 instead of 1 & 3, I would get 1, 2 and the next add would be 3 ?

This would need to update all field names and input text entries that are being updated.

Comment: I wouldn't go with all of that overhead. It seems a bit much to deal with (can you imagine if you had 10+ numbers?). Why would you want to recalc all of the indexes?

Comment: Any reason server-side to not use `phone_number[]`?

Comment: You can do it this way, but you'll be constantly running into problems like this one. What you need to do is separate your *data* from your *display* logic. Take a look at this section of Addy Osmani's Learning JavaScript Design Patterns to understand this concept: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#detailmvcmvp

Comment: @Mooseman - I may well go with server-side, but I wanted to see how the output from this would be returned. I'll be doing some testing today so will decided once I know what information is returned and in what format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding/removing you can renumber all the inputs and labels like follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_phone_number").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().before($("#phone_number_form").clone().show());
        reNumberInputs();
    });

    $("form").on("click", "[id^='remove_phone_number']", function(){
        $(this).closest("div").remove();
        reNumberInputs();
    });    
});

function reNumberInputs() {
    $("input[type='text']:visible").each(function(index, element) {
        var displayIndex = (index + 1).toString();
        element.id = "phone_number" + displayIndex;
        element.name = "phone_number" + displayIndex;
        if (index > 0) {
            $(this).prev("span").html("Phone number " + displayIndex);
            $(this).next("input").prop("id", "remove_phone_number" + displayIndex).prop("name", "remove_phone_number" + displayIndex);
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="phone_number_form" class="hidden">
    <p>
        <span>Phone number</span> : <input type="text" name="phone_number" /> 
        <input type="button" id="remove_phone_number" value="Remove" />
    </p>
</div>
<form>
    <p>
        Phone number : <input type="text" name="phone_number1" /> 
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Add phone number" id="add_phone_number" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yezw6c51/29/)

Comment: thanks this seems to do what I'm looking for. Is it possible to limit this to allow only a maximum of 5 phone number fields ?

Comment: Spotted an error with this. When run add 2 new phone number fields. These are correctly named and numbered name="phone_number2" id="phone_number2" and name="phone_number3" id="phone_number3".  If you remove Phone number 2, then Phone number 3's text is changed to 2 and  id is changed to phone_number2, but the name is still phone_number3 which mean when submitted it will be against the phone name. anyway to get the name value correct as well ?

Comment: `element.name = "phone_number" + displayIndex;` has sorted out the name value... now the remove button has the wrong value, when this doesn't cause an issue i'd like it all to match !

Comment: Just spotted a bug :( Using your fiddle - add 2 new phone number fields. remove them both, then add another new one. you can't remove it. Adding is fine removing fails. anyway around that ?

Comment: That code was a bit of a mess. I cleaned it up significantly. This should work now.

Comment: thanks this works great and I will mark it as the answer. Quick followup. `http://jsfiddle.net/zg6536nv/2/` I've pre added 2 additional fields with remove buttons. But I can't remove them. Have I missed something obvious ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the field name as phone_number[] this will be the standard.
2. If you can't change the procedure then on submit of form rename your fields by getting all the created one by one and assigning current text field values to new fields but it is not a standard method.

Hope you get your answer and if you have any other question get in touch with me on my new blog on http://www.sourabhmodi.in/. I will be happy to help you..