# increment name input in jquery script

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I need to increment the input name of a jquery script (i'm working in a jsp), the idea is when I press the button `agregar` this function would add another row of the same thing written on it, the problem is I need to increase the value of `producto`
example= in my jsp start `producto` as `producto`, when `añadir` is pressed, that value has to change to `producto1` and so on.

```
     <script>
        $(function () {
                $("#producto").on("click",".add",function() {
                    nuevaFila = '<tr>' +
                            '<td>Producto a comprar: </td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            '<select name="producto">' +
                        <c:forEach items="${producto}" var="a" >
                                '<option value="${a.idProducto}">${a.nombre}</option>' +
                        </c:forEach>
                            '</select>' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            '<input type="number" name="cantidad" maxlength="2" style="width: 40px;"/>' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            '<input type="button" class="add" value="Agregar" />' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '</tr>';
                    $("#producto").append(nuevaFila);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

i don't think is need it  but here is the jsp part

```
            <tr>
                <td>Productos a comprar: </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="producto" id="producto">
                        <c:forEach items="${producto}" var="a" >
                            <option value="${a.idProducto}">${a.nombre}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="cantidad" maxlength="2" style="width: 40px;"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="add" value="Agregar" />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

the idea is to get the name imputs in the servlet and use them in what is convenient

Comment: `<c:forEach>` won't run in the browser.... only on the server

Comment: Usually the server will treat multiple fields of the same name, eg `<input name='producto'>` as an array, which is often much easier to handle than looking for `producto1` through `producto99999`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Incrementing field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261819/jquery-incrementing-field-names)